# how to align longtable at the left side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I'm using `longtable` package to create tables, that take more than one page.
But be default longtable is centered. How to left-align a longtable?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The documentation says that one can use the optional argument

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{...}
```

for getting left alignment for a single `longtable`. Use

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
```

if you want left alignment for all `longtable` environments.

Comment: How do I left align the caption as well? As the caption is left at the center while the table has shifted to the left

Comment: Use the caption package, \usepackage[bf,labelsep=space,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}