# About the horizontal adjustment of \makebox[\textwidth][c] or [l] or [r]

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have been benefits from the post [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth) and the post [Flushright or left of a long Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173873/flushright-or-left-of-a-long-table) .

I try to use this `\makebox[\textwidth][c]` or `\makebox[\textwidth][l]` or `\makebox[\textwidth][r]`.

But it turns out that [l] is shifting the table far to right. and [r] is shifting the table far to left. And [c] is very close to what I wish, but needs some few mm adjustment to shift to a bit more left.

> Q1: Is there any function like `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{3mm}` with {3mm} shifting?

-

> Q2: Is there anyway to adjust the position locate the table somehow between `\makebox[\textwidth][c]` and `\makebox[\textwidth][l]`?

Thank you for the comments from the experts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\hspace*{3mm}\makebox[...]{.....}\hspace*{-3mm}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the cause of your slightly off spacing might be a missing `\noindent`.

As paragraphs are usually indented, when you use `\makebox` on its own line a indent is added. See below for  a comparison with and without `\noindent`:

[image]

### Notes:

- I adjusted the `\textwidth`, and added the `showframe` option to [the `geometry` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) so that the effect would be easier to see.

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=5cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
Some text

\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\textcolor{red}{CENTER}}

\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\textcolor{red}{LEFT}}


\bigskip
\noindent
But with \verb|\noindent|:
\medskip

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\textcolor{blue}{CENTER}}

\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\textcolor{blue}{LEFT}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Idear: That is one reason it is recommended to _always_ compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem, no matter how trivial it may seem.