# Left margins are different for longtable and tabular

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, longtable

I would like to use a `tabular` and a `longtable` in my document, but the left margins are not aligned.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{15cm}}
entry 1 & bla bla bla bla bla \\
entry 2 & this is a tabular
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm} p{15cm}}
entry 3 & This is a longtable \\
entry 4 & with many more lines \\
entry 5 & but it isn't aligned 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/how-to-align-longtable-at-the-left-side) is related, and so is [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/how-to-align-longtable-at-the-left-side).

Replacing `\begin{longtable}{...}` with `\begin{longtable}[l]{...}` in the code above doesn't seem to do anything.

By fumbling around, I found that by using `\setlength{\LTleft}{18pt}` my margins look pretty equal. Is there a more elegant way to have `longtables` left-aligned with `tabulars`? Can I align my tables without specifying numbers?

Comment: `longtable` is centred `tabular` is indented replace 15cm by 5cm you will see.

Comment: @touhami Good point. Can I make `longtable` indented rather than aligned?

Comment: The documentation for `longtable` says I can flush left with the `l` option, but that doesn't seem to do anything for my example.

Comment: in your example you have 15cm+2cm=17cm > `\textwidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `longtable` is centred `tabular` is indented. Section 5 in [the package documentation](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) indicates the solution. By adding `\setlength\LTleft\parindent` to the preamble, longtable will be set to flush  left,  but  indented by the usual paragraph indentation.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft\parindent

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{15cm}}
entry 1 & bla bla bla bla bla \\
entry 2 & this is a tabular
\end{tabular}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm} p{15cm}}
entry 3 & This is a longtable \\
entry 4 & with many more lines \\
entry 5 & but it isn't aligned 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

As pointed out by other members in the comments, you have set a width that is greater than `\textwidth`, in this case `tabularx` can be used to benefit from the total available width by setting the first column as `p{2cm}` and the rest of the width goes to the second column. `\noindent` was also necessary for `tabularx`.

For the `longtable` you can set the same, but, for the second column we have to calculate the remaining width. This is done by `\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-2cm\relax`. To understand this, imagine the row as `|tabcolsep||p{2cm}||tabcolsep||tabcolsep||p{length}||tabcolsep|`, then, `length` should be equal to `\linewidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep`.

Finally, I have used `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package to give the tables a professional appearance.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{2cm} X}\toprule
entry 1 & bla bla bla bla bla \\
entry 2 & this is a tabular \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\begin{longtable}{p{2cm} p{\dimexpr\linewidth-4\tabcolsep-2cm\relax}}\toprule
entry 3 & This is a longtable \\
entry 4 & with many more lines \\
entry 5 & but it isn't aligned  \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```