# Glossaries longbooktabs without page numbering shows page list in glossary header

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

I want to use the `longbooktabs` style for my glossaries but i don't want the page numbering. I read that normally this is done with the `nonumberlist` option however when i add this option i am still getting `Seiten` german for page list in the glossary header (see picture below). How can I remove this? I appreciate your suggestions!

[image: Glossaries longbooktabs still prints "Seiten" with nonumberlist option]

Here is a minimal document with the described problem:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,                                                               
    DIV=12,                                                             
    paper=A4,                                                               
    parskip=half,                                                   
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
    toc,                                        
    acronym,
    nonumberlist,
]{glossaries}

\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}

\makeglossaries     

\newacronym{CAN}{CAN}{Controller Area Network}
\newacronym{CANFD}{CANFD}{Controller Area Network Flexible Data-Rate}
\newacronym{CANH}{CAN\_H}{CAN-High Leitung} 

\begin{document}

    \acrfull{CAN} \acrfull{CANFD} \acrfull{CANH}

    \printglossary[title={Abkürzungsverzeichnis}, type=\acronymtype, style=long3col-booktabs]
    \printglossary[title={Glossar}, style=long3col-booktabs]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you make a minimal document that produces this output and add it to your question? That would make it much easier for potential answerers to reproduce the problem and start looking for a solution.

Comment: @Marijn you are absolutely right. I added a minimal document to the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is the `long-booktabs` style, which is the same as `long3col-booktabs` but then without the 3rd column. This is centered by default, if you want you can left-align it using `\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}` (from [how to align longtable at the left side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/how-to-align-longtable-at-the-left-side)).

Code:

```
\begin{document}

    \acrfull{CAN} \acrfull{CANFD} \acrfull{CANH}
    \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
    \printglossary[title={Abkürzungsverzeichnis}, type=\acronymtype, style=long-booktabs]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

A bit wider:

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{0.8\textwidth}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I just noticed that with the `long-name-desc` style i suggested below i got bad hboxes in the glossary header but with this one everything works fine. Do you know if you can make it a bit wider?

Comment: @mab0189 see edit.

Comment: Thank you very much again. You are my hero of the day :-) !

Answer (score 0):

There is another style that can be used instead in this case `long-name-desc` which isn't part of `\usepackage{glossary-longbooktabs}` but `\usepackage{glossary-longextra}` from the glossaries-extra package.